# Is it good practice to use Maven + Node.js?

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, package.json

I have read some articles and solutions how to build Node.js app with Maven, but I could not find the answer to these questions:

- Is it good practice to build Node.js app with Maven?
- Are there other alternatives to download npm modules from package.json and let it automatically install node and npm all along?

Comment: Your trying to put a square peg in round hole dragging maven into picture where focus should be on understanding PMs like bower as used with gulp/ grunt tools. Read up on them and drop maven.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue it depends on the way you deliver the software and on your build infrastructure.

Most cases where I saw people using maven to execute node commands is by circumstance. It is often easier (quicker, while probably not the best long term solution) to get node running if your team has a java background. Also most CI servers quickly run this way and the company proxy settings (often including the Nexus artifact repository) are stored in maven settings.xml. So using maven to read those and pass them along to your node build is just a pragmatic approach.

I think that's ok as long as you just use it like that (re-use infrastructure settings, but execute a node build with grunt/gulp/webpack/...).

Furthermore often the single page applications are packed as a war file to have them deployed (since a lot of companies use on application server vendor). So maven will start your node build and then create a war file to be processed further down the pipeline (often an existing one, often maven based).

Since npm has its own package hierarchy and everything I would recommend using that one, not mixing maven dependency resolution with the node package manager.

If there are no such circumstances (you have a native node support on your CI server, you can manage artifacts / node packages somwhow, you can deploy you node applications in your "cloud" without maven: do it without)

Node lacks certain enterprise features that would ease setting it up (proxy settings, internal npm hosting). And I encountered node modules that just ignore proxy settings.

On the other hand a lot of these requirements are just a habit and using node is **a good opportunity to re-think** a few things one would consider as given. If you can make things run without maven, stick with node only. I'm quite maven friendly - if that matters in this discussion :) - just to simplify weighting your requirements and inputs.